# the reason why Conflict between plugin and javascript function occured

Tags: javascript, onclick, conflict, event-listener

Few days ago I had to write code quickly and added the bad code below.

```
<td class="note_box_con" onclick="getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();">
```

After then, when I tried to use Text editor plugin written by Javascript, I found

**Text editor plugin and the function of DOM collide into each other**

Now I know what was the problem and solve it. But I cannot understand what kind of risk **getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();** has.

In my incomplete view, that code is just addEventlistener function().....

> what kind of risk **onclick="getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();"**  has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding, its a bad practice to do it this way. I would rather suggest you to use to fetch using classname or id.

If you are using some resource that adds anchor tags to your page, this will break your logic.

Following is a simulation:

```js
var count = 0;
function addAnchor(){
  var div = document.getElementById("content");
  var str = "<a href='#'>" + count++ + "</a>";
  div.innerHTML = str + div.innerHTML;
}

document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log(this.innerHTML);
  return false;
})
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>

<button onclick="addAnchor()">Add Link</button>
<a onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click()"> test </a>
```

Also, if there is a change in DOM structure, your code will not work properly. Best use a proper selector that uniquely identifies the element.

Comment: Your answer is definitely right but I think my problem was in a difference case not about disappeared selector. Is there any more possible risk? sorry for not detail

Comment: In my understanding, only risk is fetching incorrect element. It will cause unwanted issues and is not a good practice. Also if you give your code to someone else, it will be hard for him/her to debug it. Plus being an anchor tag, it might cause redirection, so I would avoid it. I would use `ID` and if not possible, then combination of selector like `parentElementClass > a`.